# Error al chekear las conexión entre oracle y mongify

Tags: oracle, ruby-on-rails, mongodb, ruby

Buenas tengo el siguiente problema con mongify,

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y mi Gemfile en la ruta C:\Ruby25-x64\lib\ruby\gems\2.5.0\gems\mongify-1.3.2 contiene:

```
source "http://rubygems.org"

# Specify your gem's dependencies in template_del.gemspec
gemspec

gem 'activerecord-oracle_enhanced-adapter', '~> 5.2.0'
```

## Y mi database.config:

```
sql_connection do
    adapter 'oracle_enhanced'
    host 'localhost'
    database 'prueba_estrella'
end

mongodb_connection do
    adapter 'mongo'
    host 'localhost'
    database 'test_monfy'
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Veo un par de potenciales problemas/soluciones.

Primero, ¿has probado instalando la gema requerida en vez de editar el `Gemfile`? (porque supongo tu agregaste esa linea `gem 'activerecord-oracle_enhanced-adapter', '~> 5.2.0'` al Gemfile, ¿cierto? no es algo común ir a editar el código fuente de una gema para que funcione, debería funcionar sin realizar eso).

Además creo que tu problema está en que mongify requiere una versión de `activerecord` (parte de `rails`) [menor a `5.0`](https://github.com/anlek/mongify/blob/master/mongify.gemspec#L15) (`4.2.11.1` como se ve en tu log), sin embargo la versión de `oracle-enhanced` requerida para `4.2` es la [`1.6`](https://github.com/rsim/oracle-enhanced#rails-42), no la `5.2.0` como tienes en ese `Gemfile`.

Creo que debería funcionar removiendo la línea que agregaste al `Gemfile` e instalando lo siguiente:

```
gem install activerecord-oracle_enhanced-adapter -v '1.6.9'
```